# Proper jQuery technique to disable button with ajax post then re-enble button onComplete

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a button that performs an ajax post -- I want to disable the button, then perform my work, then upon completion -- I want to re-enable the button. My interaction includes swapping out the image button (to a grayed out image button), and presenting a spinner. When complete, I hide the spinner and restore the original button image.

My approach includes unbinding, then rebinding the click event.

Here's my code -- it works great -- but, I want to know if this is a proper/efficient/acceptable strategy?

```
// Update club name
$j('#btnUpdateClubName').bind('click', updateClubName);

function updateClubName() {
    var $this = $j(this);
    var $spinner = $this.next('.spinner');
    var renderURL = RES.BuildClubUpdateURL("UpdateClubName");

    $this.ajaxStart(function() {
        $this.attr("src", imgPathSaveAndUpdateBtnDisabled).unbind('click').addClass('wait-cursor');
        $spinner.show();
    });

    $j.ajax({ type: "POST", data: $j('#hidStandingOrderId, #txtClubName, #clubOrderIdEditClubName').serialize(), url: renderURL, dataType: 'html', contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        success: function(data) {
            // do some stuff
            }
        }
    });

    $this.ajaxComplete(function() {
        $spinner.hide();
        $this.attr("src", imgPathSaveAndUpdateBtn).bind('click', updateClubName).removeClass('wait-cursor');
        $j("#cbEditClubName").colorbox.close();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have works but it is a bit wasteful, as it adds a *new* `ajaxStart` and `ajaxComplete` handler each time the function runs, I would make one suggestion though, change your [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) call to be more specific since you have the information.  If you change this:

```
.unbind('click')
```

To this:

```
.unbind('click', updateClubName)
```

You can have other `click` events without the [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) interfering, it'll *only* unbind that one handler.

---

An overall better alternative (*to me*, you can debate whether it's "better") without rebinding would be to store a variable to know you're currently posting using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), for example:

```
$j('#btnUpdateClubName').bind('click', updateClubName);

function updateClubName() {
    if($.data(this, "posting")) return false;   //are we posting? abort!
    $.data(this, "posting", true);              //set variable
    var $this = $j(this);
    var $spinner = $this.next('.spinner');
    var renderURL = RES.BuildClubUpdateURL("UpdateClubName");

    $this.attr("src", imgPathSaveAndUpdateBtnDisabled).addClass('wait-cursor');
    $spinner.show();

    $j.ajax({ type: "POST", data: $j('#hidStandingOrderId, #txtClubName, #clubOrderIdEditClubName').serialize(), url: renderURL, dataType: 'html', contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        success: function(data) {
            // do some stuff
            $spinner.hide();
            $this.attr("src", imgPathSaveAndUpdateBtn).removeClass('wait-cursor')
                 .data("posting", false);   //clear it out, ready to post again
            $j("#cbEditClubName").colorbox.close();
        }
    });
}
```

With this approach if you're doing a POST the data for "posting" is `true`, and future clicks just abandon out...not until the response comes back and your `success` code runs is the button re-enabled.  It's the same *effect* but no duplicate handlers and no re/un-binding.

Comment: the second solution is much better